# Order stability problems in vector function

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, formatting, dplyr

I am trying to write a function that quantifies numeric input by order of magnitude, using SI prefixes and an optional suffix. For example:

```
1        => 1
23.4     => 23.4
1001     => 1.0k
12345678 => 12.3MB (i.e., "B" is the suffix)
```

My first attempt mostly works:

```
format.quantified <- function(n, base = 1000, suffix = "", multiplier = c("k", "M", "G", "T", "P"), threshold = 0.8, sep = "") {
  # Return n, quantified by order of magnitude (relative to base,
  # defaulting to SI prefixes) to one decimal place (or exactly, for
  # non-quantified integers) with an optional suffix for units
  n <- as.numeric(n)
  exponent <- trunc(log(n, base = base))

  is.decimal <- n != trunc(n)

  # Move up to the next multiplier if we're close enough
  # FIXME This condition only applies to the first element, but the
  # increment will be applied to everything
  # if (n / (base ^ (exponent + 1)) >= threshold) { exponent <- exponent + 1 }

  paste(
    ifelse(exponent | is.decimal, sprintf("%.1f", n / (base ^ exponent)), n),
    paste(ifelse(exponent, multiplier[exponent], ""), suffix, sep = ""),
    sep = sep)
}
```

However, it suffers from two problems:

1. I would like to provide a threshold value which will quantify the value to the next order of magnitude when crossed. This doesn't work in the above because I'm new to R and was surprised when I found that my function is applied to the entirety of the input data at once (rather than row-by-row).
2. With this new-found vectorisation knowledge, it appears to suffer from a subtle, reordering bug that I can't determine the cause of:

   ```
   > format.quantified(c(1,1000,1000000,1000000000))
   [1] "1"    "1.0M" "1.0G" "1.0k"
   ```

   Interestingly, this bug does not manifest itself when applied to a data frame with `dplyr`'s `mutate` function (e.g., `mutate(data, foo = format.qualified(foo))`)

I attempted to solve this problem by appreciating the vectorised input and treating everything accordingly:

```
format.quantified <- (function() {
  # Use a closure to define the default SI magnitude prefixes
  prefix.default <- data.frame(exponent = c(0,  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6),
                               prefix   = c("", "k", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E"))

  is.prefix  <- function(x) { is.data.frame(x) && all(c("exponent", "prefix") %in% colnames(x)) }
  is.decimal <- function(x) { x != trunc(x) }

  function(n, suffix = "", threshold = 0.8, base = 1000, prefix.alternative = NA, sep = "") {
    # Return n, quantified by order of magnitude (relative to base)
    # to one decimal place (or exactly, for non-quantified integers)
    # with an optional suffix for units
    prefix <- prefix.default
    if (is.prefix(prefix.alternative)) {
      prefix <- filter(prefix, !exponent %in% prefix.alternative$exponent) %>%
                bind_rows(prefix.alternative)
    }

    q <- data.frame(n = as.numeric(n), exponent = trunc(log(n, base = base))) %>%
         mutate(quantified = n / (base ^ exponent)) %>%
         merge(prefix, by = "exponent", all.x = TRUE)

    # TODO Threshold logic using filter and recombining with bind_rows

    paste(
      ifelse(q$exponent | is.decimal(q$n), sprintf("%.1f", q$quantified), q$n),
      paste(q$prefix, suffix, sep = ""),
      sep = sep)
  }
})()
```

This appears to have solved the reordering bug in the original:

```
> format.quantified(c(1,1000,1000000,1000000000))
[1] "1"    "1.0k" "1.0M" "1.0G"
> format.quantified(123)
[1] "123"
```

However, before I even tried implementing the threshold logic, I noticed that when applied against a data frame with `mutate`, the ordering in the output is completely messed up. On closer examination, it turns out the stability breaks down whenever the input isn't in numerical order:

```
> format.quantified(c(1000000,1,1000,1000000,1000000000))
[1] "1e+06" "1.0k"  "1.0M"  "1.0M"  "1.0G"
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT** FWIW, my threshold logic for the second version of my function is as follows:

```
q <- data.frame(n = as.numeric(n), exponent = trunc(log(n, base = base))) %>%
     mutate(quantified = n / (base ^ exponent))

q.below <- filter(q, quantified <  base * threshold)
q.above <- filter(q, quantified >= base * threshold) %>%
           mutate(exponent = exponent + 1, quantified = quantified / base)

Q <- bind_rows(q.below, q.above) %>%
     merge(prefix, by = "exponent", all.x = TRUE)
```

Needless to say, this doesn't make the order stability problem any better!

Comment: This `format.quantified <- (function() {` kind of function definition looks a little strange to me, especially if you want to use the function with arguments later on, as you did.

Comment: It's a closure to set up constants, so they're not uselessly redefined on each invocation while not polluting the global namespace. The return of the closure (see inner `function`) is the actual function, which takes the arguments. I don't know if it's idiomatic R, but it works :)